# Why isn't the format date of the Rails view being properly displayed with the initializer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, erb, view-helpers

On my view view, I have the following format I want to output:

```
<tr>
  <th>Released:</th>
  <td>
   <%= movie.release_at.to_s(:release_date) %>
   (<%= time_ago_in_words(movie.release_at) %>)
  </td>
</tr>
```

The exact format I want is "Month Day, Year", so I created an initialize file with the following:

```
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%B %e, %Y"
```

My database schema has a movies table with a field called `release_at` with the data type of `datetime` this is where I am attempting to extract the the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've set the default Date format, but you said that the column is a datetime.  If you want the default Date format that you specified, you'll need to convert the value to a date:

```
<%= movie.release_at.to_date.to_s %>
```

Comment: You where faster than me! Is the to_s really necessary? I would add this for those who want some customization <%= l @movie.release_at.to_date, format: :your_specific_format %>. Here is the documentation: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats

Comment: @codingaddicted, the `to_s` is not strictly needed in this case since we're using the default format.